# USB transfer grant: disable

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, usb, usb-connection-mode

Is there a way to disable the dialog below:
[image]

Android version 6.0.1

Comment: It's a dialog, not a notification. :-)

Answer (score -1):

I Think you can't disable this.But if you search for the code "who" is start that on pc or as root user can be a way tó disable this.Sorry for my errors i am in hungary country/Magyarország 
Have a nice day!